# Tradingview bar color alert

Tags: performance, bar-chart, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

I'd like to set an alert in Tradingview pinescript v5, if barcolor(color.green) is true. Can anyone help? Thanks much!

I'd like to set an alert in Tradingview pinescript v5, if barcolor(color.green) is true. Can anyone help? Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

In pinescript v5, you can't retrieve the color of a bar.
You can just apply a color.

Comment: well I have a script that  paints a bar under certain condition, but I would like to set an alert if that condition is true, and unfortunately the script itself is pretty complicated and only way around to get good entry is when the bar is painted. I'm trying to find another way to pinpoint  the colored bars, any suggestions would be much appreciated